# why many glitches are coming in .ts file

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, mp4, vlc

I am working streaming(STB) project.

Progratically I have pulled streaming video data pulled into android devices(Set-top box).
pushed test.ts into my location machine and played with VLC media player. The video, it is showing many glitches.

Can you please help why it is showing many glitches in the downloaded videos?

Comment: can you clarify a "glitch". do you have any code, or manifest files we can reference?

Comment: I found the issue. I have downloaded an encrypted video.